# Validation html form within JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, validation

Is there any library or JavaScript to create a form with validation using the JSON data?

For example, if I have JSON something like `{firstname: Jhon, lastname: Doe, age:32}` and I have an HTML input form on an external system with fields:

- First name
- Last name

When visitor inputs their name on a form, on the backend will check the validation from JSON data.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You can make use of Joi to validate your objects. Please take a look here: https://github.com/hapijs/joi

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion will check this

Answer (score 0):

1. Load the necessary jQuery and underscore.js libraries in the document.

   ```
   <script src="/path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/path/to/underscore.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. Load the Bootstrap's stylesheet to beautify the generated form fields.

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet"href="/path/to/bootstrap.css">
   ```
3. GIVE a class name for the form

   ```
   <form class="form">
   ```
4. Call the function on the form element and define the form fields in the JSON

   ```
   $('form').jsonForm({
   "schema": {
   "name": {
     "title": "your title",
     "description": "Your description",
     "type": "your type",
   },
     "enum": [
       "male",
       "female",
       "alien"
     ]
   }});
   ```
5. Validate the data on submit using the `onSubmit` callback.

   ```
   $('form').jsonForm({


   onSubmit: function (errors, values) {
   if (errors) {
     // do something
   }
   else {
     // do something
   }});
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Using React and node.js may be a more future safe solution since it's become industry standard... have you looked at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jsonschema-form ?

It looks like a pretty solid repo from the weekly downloads standpoint and seems to fit your use case well (I may try it out myself). The only catch would be that there's a learning curve to getting up to speed with the world of React and nodejs.  I would highly recommend it though if you haven't already.  Some great resources to get started would include:

- https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/
- https://nodejs.org/en/
- https://code.visualstudio.com/

From there it can become a deep dive but I find it fun. Good Luck!